# Symfony Security FOSOAuthServerBundle public and private routes

Tags: symfony, fosoauthserverbundle

I am using the FOSOAuthBundle for my REST application

I would like most of my routes to require authorization however there are a few that should have public access

I have the following in my security.yml:

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    oauth_token:
        pattern:    ^/login
        security:   false

    api:
        pattern:    ^/
        fos_oauth:  true
        stateless:  true
        anonymous:  false

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY ] }
```

For example:

I have a Products `Entity` and `Controller`

I would like the `CRUD` operations to be private except for `Read`

So: `POST, PUT, DELETE on /products(/:id)` should be private while `GET` should be public.

I have tried adding the following to the access_control:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/products$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY ] }
```

I thought this would open up all `methods` on `/products` but I get the error:

```
{
  "error": "access_denied",
  "error_description": "OAuth2 authentication required"
}
```

I have many `entities` and `controllers` I am trying to apply this to.

How would I go about opening up specific routes (including the `method` requirements)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make new firewall with regex and set it like this. You have to put it in front of your api firewall in order to match this regex first.

```
api_anonym_area:
      pattern: (^/api/products/.*)
      methods: [GET]
      security: false
```

Or you can make it

```
api_anonym_area:
      pattern: (^/api/products/.*)
      methods: [GET]
      anonymous: true
```

with

```
access_control:
- { path: ^/api/products/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
```

In first case you wont have token, in in second case you will have token (its good when you expect authenticated or anonymous users to come).

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, best way would be to code the permissions in the controllers, I don't think this is possible via the security.yml configuration.

You should remove:

```
 - { path: ^/, roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY ] }
```

And manage permissions inside the controller actions, for example (taken from symfony documentation at http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html)

```
public function updateProduct($id)
{
    // The second parameter is used to specify on what object the role is tested.
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_ADMIN', null, 'Unable to access this page!');

    // Old way :
    // if (false === $this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
    //     throw $this->createAccessDeniedException('Unable to access this page!');
    // }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: You can also use annotations to achieve this if you wish

`* @Secure(roles="ROLE_ADMIN")`